# PDF document: How to disable redirection to the Maps app on sentences like "1987 Wall Street"?

Tags: pdf, links

In a PDF document, apps such as Preview and Skim attempt to redirect to the Maps app when clicking on words that look like an address, e.g. "1987 Wall Street", instead of properly displaying the hyperlinks. How can I disable this "feature"?

**Undesired Effect:**

[image]

**Desired Effect:**

[image]

Link to the PDF document for testing, if needed: [PDF](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/22f6a0a124cda0de89c5d745212124d220231007032222/5bdffd)

Comment: Do you just want to remove the dotted line?

Comment: @Thinkr. Yes, I'd like to remove the dotted line. And even better would be to remove the "address recognition" capability of PDF viewers like Preview and Skim. Removing the line would go most of the way. Removing the little arrow next to the number 1987 on the screenshot would be even better. If you know a way, I'd love to hear! Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can find something.